# SmoothScroll scrolls too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

im working on my new portfolio and im having a problem that i cant fix without help.
Here you have a link of my website so far: `www.jsfiddle.net/Cessum/pmaefrjo/`

What i want is that when you click on creaties the website scrolls too far. To explain it better you have to click on creaties and then remove the white menu bar with inspect element.
After you have done that  you can see that there is red color under (behind) the menu bar. That is the problem i want to fix. It should stop scrolling before the red gets behind the white menu bar.

Can you help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the height of the header (menu bar) from scrollTop and it will work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the height you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/pmaefrjo/1/

```
 $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50 // the height of #MenuBar
}, 1000);
```

OR

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - $('#MenuBar').height()
}, 1000);
```